# Reloading UITableView resets frame after animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've been stuck on this issue and I'm really curious why it's happening. I've re-created my issue using a simple example shown below. I placed a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell (containing a UILabel at the center of the cell) at the bottom of my view with a UISearchBar at the top.

When the keyboard pops up, I animate the UITableView to change its frame to fit the space below the UISearchBar and above the keyboard. Now when I enter any search text and reload the UITableView, the UITableView changes its frame prior to the animation.

Initially -

```
UITableView Frame: {{0, 223}, {320, 237}} - {{x, y},{width, height}}
```

After Animation -

```
UITableView Frame: {{0, 44}, {320, 436}} - {(x, y),(width, height)}
```

When I enter any search text - `UITableView Frame: {{0, 223}, {320, 237}} - {{x, y},{width, height}}`

I noticed that this only happens with a custom UITableViewCell. I've searched around for an answer but haven't found anything. I've tried adding the UILabel as a subview to the contentView in the custom UITableViewCell but that didn't work. So my question is, how can I prevent the UITableView from reverting its frame back to its original value?

**EDIT**: Here's the code that I change the UITableView Frame after animation.

```
- (void)keyboardDisplayed:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardValue = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [keyboardValue CGRectValue];

    CGRect frame = self.testTabl.frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.testSearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.testSearchBar.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.height = keyboardFrame.origin.y - frame.origin.y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.testTabl setFrame:frame];
    }];

    NSLog(@"TableView Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.testTabl.frame));
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say anything about this without seeing your code. My first guess would be that you only do the animation and fail to set the actual frame to the new value.

Comment: Just edited my post with my code.

Comment: If anyone runs into this issue, I just used a Search Display Controller instead of trying to work with the animations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it explains the behavior you are seeing, but the main issue in your code is that you need to use the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey instead. Something like the following should work:

```
- (void)keyboardDisplayed:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGPoint endPoint = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;
    CGFloat duration = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    CGRect frame = self.testTabl.frame;
    frame.size.height = [self.testTabl convertPoint:endPoint fromView:nil].y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self.testTabl setFrame:frame];
    }];

    NSLog(@"TableView Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.testTabl.frame));
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I've tested your code but the UITableView doesn't set its frame correctly. I get the following:

    Keyboard Info: {0, 264}
    TableView Frame: {{0, 223}, {320, 21}}

It's a very odd behavior and I think its because of the custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: 264 seems OK for the keyboard. With your frame.origin.y at 223, then the 21 for the height is also correct. The weird thing is the y value of 223 for the frame, which must already be there before the keyboard is displayed.